# Remove isLeapMonth: false

Tags: swift, nsdatecomponents

the following code should return the numbers of days since cell's creation, which it does, but it also returns `isLeapMonth: false`. Why is that? How can I remove it?

```
let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
cell.textLabel?.text = itemArray[indexPath.row].title
let startDate = itemArray[indexPath.row].dateCreated
let currentDate = Date()
let components = Set<Calendar.Component>([.day])
let differenceOfDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents(components, from: startDate!, to: currentDate)
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(differenceOfDate)"
return cell
```

[image]

Comment: Converting `DateComponents` to a `String` using string interpolation is not a good way to display the results to a user. Format the date components yourself so it appears in your desired format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `differenceOfDate` is of type `DateComponents` and this doesn't return you a number. If you need to get number of days, you can get this number by getting `day` property of `DateComponents`

```
Calendar.current.dateComponents(components, from: startDate!, to: currentDate).day!
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want the number of days, you should extract just the `day` value from the resulting `DateComponents` and print that number as you desire.

```
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(differenceOfDate.day!) days"
```

Note that the use of `!` is safe here because you specifically requested the `.day` component.